# What is the best workflow for an IoT client to receive the new PEM certificate when the old one expires?

Tags: ssl-certificate, esp32, mosquitto

I'm setting up an Ubuntu machine to work as an MQTT server. It is a MOSQUITTO server. The clients of this server are based on the ESP32 microcontroller (ESPRESSIF). (I'm using the ESP-IDF framework.)

The server is using SSL transport. So each client must have the server's PEM certificate. The problem is that this certificate has an expiration date. So, I still don't understand how, in practice, clients will receive the new PEM certificate when the current one expires.

Can anyone point me to a practical workflow on how to grant the new certificate to all clients?

Regards

Comment: If you are doing it right you should only have to update when the CA certificate expires (which should be multiple years from now), not when the server cert changes.

Comment: I was confused why the Let's Encrypt certificate expires every 30 days. However, MQTT server and client certificates do not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As hardillb already pointed out, the device should use a CA cert to verify the server's cert. If you're on a custom PKI then the expiration of the CA cert is up to you to choose - perhaps it could stay valid for the entire projected lifetime of your devices. In such case there are no updates needed on the device side, and you can rotate the actual server certificate whenever you want (as long as it's signed by the CA).

Or, if you want to build a ghetto solution, just set the server's custom certificate to be valid for 100 years and never change it :)

If you really need to update your CA cert in devices, it's possible but not always practical (hence the suggestions for avoiding updates).

If you hardcode the cert into the firmware image, just make sure to update each and every one of them before the cert expires. If there are not many devices and you have physical access to them, perhaps you can just re-flash them. Otherwise you need to build an OTA update solution and ensure each device has completed a firmware upgrade before the cert expires. Advice on how to build OTA solutions is a rather long discussion itself, so I won't go into details. Espressif has a reasonably good [client-side HTTPS OTA library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/esp_https_ota.html). While the device side is not really complicated there's still a fair bit of work involved, especially if you want to monitor and control this process from some central location. You probably need to design and implement it yourself.

Or alternatively you could store the certificate in the device's Flash (perhaps in a NVS partition or a file system) in which case it could be updated separately from the firmware image. The update process would probably involve detecting a cert near expiry and downloading a new one - perhaps from the MQTT server itself. But it's all yours to write :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer! :-) You're right! If I want to use certificates with short validity, I will have to create an automatic method of sending a new certificate myself. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tarmo's answer, to ensure a smooth transition between two server certificates follow either of the two approaches. This is especially true if you have multiple devices that are not updated at the same time and want to avoid downtime.

1. Compile both the new and old server cert into the firmware
2. Cross-sign the new server cert with the old one

For case 1, the microcontrollers will have both certificates, and therefore pick whichever the server is currently using. As the server switches certificates, so do the microcontrollers. To transition, generate a new certificate, update the firmware on all microcontrollers to have the new and old certificate, and only then switch the certificate that the server uses.

For case 2, the new certificate will be trusted as it has been signed by the old certificate that is already trusted by the microcontroller. Using this approach, first issue the new certificate, then update the server to use the new certificate. Subsequently update the firmware on all microcontrollers to use the new certificate. If expiry of certificates is checked by the microcontrollers, ensure that there is an overlap in the certificate validity.

Alternatively to compiling the certificate into the firmware, it is also possible to read it from the file system (LittleFS is recommended). It would require the firmware to download the new certificate via HTTPS (possibly triggered by an MQTT message) and save it locally. If the updates are frequent, it might also be required to delete old certificates from the file system.

As reference, [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) uses the second approach to ensure that there is a smooth transition in the trust of its issued certificates.